# Why is “的” not necessary when talking about someone's body parts?

Tags: grammar

I am learning Mandarin using Lingodeer and I've encountered the sentence, “这个女孩眼睛大” and I am wondering why it isn't necessary to refer to the girl's eyes with “的” in this sentence? I know that “的” can be left out when referring to someone you're intimate with or related to but I don't think your eyes fall into either of those categories...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In 这个女孩眼睛大,  这个女孩 (this **girl**) is the subject and 眼睛大 is an adjectival phrase for it. Meaning "[这个眼睛大的][**女孩**]" (this girl with big eyes)

In 这个女孩的眼睛大,  女孩的眼睛 (this girl's **eyes**) is the subject and 大 is an adjective for it. Meaning "[**这个女孩的眼睛**][很大]" (this girl's eyes are big)

Similar example:

[他][眼大] = [he] [is big-eyed]

[他的眼][大] = [his eyes] [are big]

[他][手快] = [he] [is fast-handed]

[他的手][快] = [his hands] [are fast]

Answer (score 2):

It is actually related to the sense you describe, but not exactly the same. You should think of dropping "的" as implying that there is an *intimate connection*, in a *general* sense and not specifically "romance", between the subject and the possessed.

You are intimately possessed of your eyes as they are a part of your body, hence, you can drop "的".

That said, it is not *wrong* to use "的" in that you won't be understood if you do, but it does add a more formalizing air.